# Why is my timer not running on widget #2 when it is started on widget #1?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, stream

I am using `provider` to create a class called `GlobalsProvider` that holds some global variables. It needs to hold the current login state of the user, so to do that I need 2 things: a global boolean variable for `loggedIn` and a stream that makes a call to a SQL Server stored procedure to see if the user's login is still valid.

Right now I'm simulating a "stream" by just having flutter make the call to get the login state every 10 seconds. I was able to get the stream working by running it in `login.dart` - it worked fine there. However, I would like for the stream to be global so I want to move this into `GlobalsProvider`. That way, if the stream of the login state suddenly says that the user is no longer allowed to be logged in, I can close any widget that the user is working in, go back to the login screen, and prevent the user from being able to hit the back button to go back and do work while not logged in.

Right now my stream only runs once, but it should be firing every 10 seconds. I know it's not working because I'm not getting print statements every 10 seconds.

**GlobalsProvider:**

```
Timer? timer;

void startLoginStream(/*...parms...*/) {
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => loginStream(/*...parms...*/);

    notifyListeners();
}

void loginStream(/*...parms...*/) async {
        final previousLoggedIn = loggedIn;
    
        await sqlConnect(/*...parms...*/);
    
        var res = await SqlConn.readData("exec spHandheldLogin");
    
        res = json.decode(res);
        res = res[0]; //Gets the first object in the list. This is fine because this SP will only ever return 1 row
        var loginState = res['LoginState'];
    
        if (kDebugMode) {print('${StaticGlobals.tagATS} loginStream loginState: ${loginState.toString()}');}
    
        if (loginState == 1) {
          loggedIn = true;
          loggedInUser = username;
        } else {
          loggedIn = false;
          loggedInUser = '';
        }
    
        await sqlDisconnect();
    
        //Only need to update the listeners if the login state changes
        if (loggedIn != previousLoggedIn) {
          notifyListeners();
        }
    }
```

**login.dart:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
        builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Login'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                   Expanded(
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final status = await value.login(/*...parms...*/);

                        if (value.loggedIn == true) { //If login was successful, start the "stream"
                          value.loginStream(/*...parms...*/);
                        } else {
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                              msg: "ERROR",
                              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                          );
                        }
                      },
                      child: const Text('Submit'),
                    ),
                  )
                  //...
```

**wrapper.dart:**

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
      if (value.loggedIn == true) {
        return const Forms(); //widget #2
      } else {
        return const Login(); //widget #1
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my button press I was calling the wrong function. I was doing `value.loginStream` when I should have been doing `value.startLoginStream`. Both of these functions exist, so that's why I didn't get an error.